# How to connect Redpanda cluster and topic to Redpanda Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, confluent-schema-registry, redpanda

I am trying to connect a running redpanda kafka cluster to a redpanda schema registry, so that the schema registry verifies incoming messages to the topic, and/or messages being read from the topic.

I am able to add a schema to the registry and read it back with curl requests, as well as add messages to the kafka topic I created in the redpanda cluster.

My question is, how to implement the schema registry with a topic in a kafka cluster? Like how do I instruct the schema registry and/or the kafka topic to validate incoming messages against the schema I added to the registry?

Thanks for your help or a point in the right direction!

Relevant info:

Cluster & topic creation:
https://vectorized.io/docs/guide-rpk-container

```
rpk container start -n 3
rpk topic create -p 6 -r 3 new-topic --brokers <broker1_address>,<broker2_address>...
```

Schema Registry creation:
https://vectorized.io/blog/schema_registry/

Command to add a schema:

```
curl -s \
  -X POST \
  "http://localhost:8081/subjects/sensor-value/versions" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
  -d '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"sensor_sample\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"},{\"name\":\"identifier\",\"type\":\"string\",\"logicalType\":\"uuid\"},{\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"long\"}]}"}' \
  | jq
```

Answer (score 1):

The client is responsible for such integration. For example, the Confluent Schema Registry includes `KafkaAvroSerializer` Java class that wraps an HTTP Client that handles the schema registration and message validation. The broker doesn't handle "topic schemas", since schemas are really per-record. Unless RedPanda has something similar, broker-side validation is only offered by [Enterprise "Confluent Server."](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html)

RedPanda is primarily a server that exposes a Kafka-compatible API; I assume it is up to you to create (de)serializer interfaces for your respective client languages.  There is a Python example on [Vectorized Github](https://github.com/vectorizedio/redpanda-examples/blob/main/clients/python/pandaproxy_registry.py).
That being said, the Confluent Schema Registry should work with RedPanda as well, and so you can use its serializers and HTTP client libraries with it.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I will be looking into how to use Confluent's serializers and HTTP client libraries, as I am working with a Confluent cluster and schema registry container now. Good to know about the Enterprise offering too, as I am in an enterprise environment and once we are in prod that could be an option.